# How to convert images to TFRecords with tf.data.Dataset in most efficient way possible

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, parallel-processing, tfrecord

I am absolutely baffled by how many unhelpful error messages I've received while trying to use this supposedly simple API to write TFRecords in a manner that doesn't take 30 minutes every time I have a new dataset.

### Task:

I'd like to feed a list of image paths and a list of labels to a tf.data.Dataset, parse them in parallel to read the images and encode as tf.train.Examples, use tf.data.Dataset.shard to distribute them into different TFRecord shards (e.g. train-001-of-010.tfrecord, train-002-of-010.tfrecord, etc.), and for each shard finally write them to the corresponding file.

Since I've been debugging this for hours I haven't gotten any single particular error to fix, otherwise I would provide it. I've struggled to find any up to date tutorial that doesn't either (a) come from 2017 and use queue runners, (b) use a tf.Session (I'm using tensorflow 1.15 but official docs keep telling me to phase out sessions), (c) Conveniently do the record creating in pure python, which makes a simple tutorial but is too slow for any actual application, or (d) use already created TFRecords and just skip the whole process.

If necessary, I can put together an example of what I'm talking about. But since I'm getting stuck at every level of the process, at the moment it seems unhelpful.

### Tldr:

If anyone has utilized tf.data.Dataset to create TFRecord shards in parallel please point me in a better direction than google has.